# Dev Express Customize Property Grid Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I am using Dev Express PropertyGrid control to display an complex object. Everything is looking good but I want to be able to customize some aspects, so here they are :

1)When displaying a list of items, for every row instead of [0],[1],[2]... index, I want to be able to display a friendly name.

I implemented ICustomTypeDescriptor interface for my Collection:

```
public class CustomObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<PropertyGridWorkSheetViewModel>, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public CustomObservableCollection(IEnumerable<PropertyGridWorkSheetViewModel> items) :
        base(items)
    { }

    public override string ToString() => $"{this.Items.Count()} Worksheets Available";

    #region ICustomTypeDescriptor impl 

    public String GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
    }

    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    }

    public String GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
    }

    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(this, true);
    }

    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Called to get the properties of this type. Returns properties with certain
    /// attributes. this restriction is not implemented here.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="attributes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return GetProperties();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called to get the properties of this type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        // Create a collection object to hold property descriptors
        var pds = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(null);

        // Iterate the list of employees
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            // Create a property descriptor for the employee item and add to the property descriptor collection
            var pd = new CustomCollectionPropertyDescriptor(this, i);
            pds.Add(pd);
        }
        // return the property descriptor collection
        return pds;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Also extended the PropertyDescriptor class for my custom collection like this :

```
 public class CustomCollectionPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private CustomObservableCollection collection = null;
    private int index = -1;

    public CustomCollectionPropertyDescriptor(CustomObservableCollection coll, int idx) :
        base("#" + idx.ToString(), null)
    {
        this.collection = coll;
        this.index = idx;
    }

    public override AttributeCollection Attributes
    {
        get
        {
            return new AttributeCollection(null);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.collection.GetType();
        }
    }

    public override string DisplayName => "DisplayName";

    public override string Description => "Description";

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return this.collection[index];
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "#" + index.ToString(); }
    }

    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return this.collection[index].GetType(); }
    }

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        // this.collection[index] = value;
    }
}
```

but without any success, Property Grid is displaying [0],[1] ... indexes for every row of the collection

And 2nd aspect :

I would like to be able to bind my row data to the checkbox present on every row of my Collection, and then write my own logic, just use that checkbox.

I have attached an image to describe visual my two requests : 
https://ibb.co/dizwqS

Comment: Please open another question for your second question as it is a seperate issue and can/should be answered on its own.